# use existing login table with asp.net core identity service

Tags: identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I have an existing live application with its own login table which has all the user info stored. Now we have decided to make a mobile app for part of the application. For that we have decided to use asp.net core identity service. What ever articles/blog/videos I have found they all show how to create a new DB and use identity tables. As for us, we cannot use the new identity tables and need to stick with our own login table as it has been used very much throughout the system and application is heavily dependent on it.

So, my question is, is there any way of using ASP.NET core identity with existing database system?

thanks heaps,
Maulik

Comment: This may be helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I think more customization is now available in Core 2.1 - or at least more documentation - not sure yet :-) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do use tables from Identity, however they do not have the same name as the default one. I guess if you customize the fields definitions you could map most of your fields.

Map of an entity property to a column:

```
b.Property<long>(u => u.Id).HasColumnName("MyIdColumn")
```

Below you will find extensions that you may use during the init of your builder.
Note the "ToTable" method, which is used to override default table names.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Init MS.Identity tables + custom AppUser table
    /// </summary>
    public static void InitIdentity(this ModelBuilder builder, string tablesPrefix = "Identity_")
    {
        builder.InitBaseIdentity(tablesPrefix);
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<long>>(b => b.ToTable($"{tablesPrefix}UserRoles"));
        builder.Entity<AppRole>(b => b.ToTable($"{tablesPrefix}Roles"));
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<long>>(b => b.ToTable($"{tablesPrefix}RoleClaims"));

    }

    public static void InitBaseIdentity(this ModelBuilder builder, string tablesPrefix = "Identity_")
    {
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<long>>(b => b.ToTable($"{tablesPrefix}UserLogins"));
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<long>>(b => b.ToTable($"{tablesPrefix}UserClaims"));
        builder.Entity<AppUser>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable($"{tablesPrefix}Users");
            b.Property<long>(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
            b.Property<int>(u => u.AccessFailedCount);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp).IsConcurrencyToken();
            b.Property<string>(u => u.Email).HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);
            b.Property<bool>(u => u.EmailConfirmed);
            b.Property<bool>(u => u.LockoutEnabled);
            b.Property<DateTimeOffset?>(u => u.LockoutEnd);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.NormalizedEmail).HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.NormalizedUserName).HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.PasswordHash);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.PhoneNumber);
            b.Property<bool>(u => u.PhoneNumberConfirmed);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.SecurityStamp);
            b.Property<bool>(u => u.TwoFactorEnabled);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.UserName).HasAnnotation("MaxLength", 256);
            b.HasKey(u => u.Id);
            b.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasName("EmailIndex");
            b.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasName("UserNameIndex").IsUnique();
            b.Property(u => u.About).HasMaxLength(255);
            b.Property(u => u.Birthdate);
            b.Property(e => e.CountryCode).IsRequired().HasColumnType("char(2)");
            b.Property(u => u.Country).HasMaxLength(50);
            b.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(50);
            b.Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(50);
            b.Property(u => u.Gender);

            b.Property(e => e.CreationDate).HasColumnType("datetime").HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()");
            b.Property(e => e.LastUpdate).HasColumnType("datetime").HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()");
        });
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<long>>(b =>
        {
            b.Property<long>(u => u.UserId);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.LoginProvider);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.Name);
            b.Property<string>(u => u.Value);
            b.HasKey(nameof(IdentityUserToken<long>.UserId), nameof(IdentityUserToken<long>.LoginProvider), nameof(IdentityUserToken<long>.Name));
            b.ToTable($"{tablesPrefix}UserTokens");
        });
    }
```

However this does not solve the authentication issue, just the mapping of tables. You will also need to customize the way the authentication is done (password check).
However I am not sure of which gain you will get with identity as it seems you would have duplicated/uncompatible login strategies. You may have to keep one or the other.

Comment: hi Jean,thanks for the reply. This is what we have decided to do. As I have mentioned, we are writing a mobile app for the existing application so want to use the new features as there are some issues with current authentication mechanism. Wanted  to know any easier way of using the existing tables. But looks like there is no such thing out of the box. thanks, Maulik

Comment: Just curious, which solution did you use? How did you solve the issue?

Comment: hi Jean, we are doing something similar what you have suggested. It is not an elegant solution but doing its job. I have left this question open just in case. I am up voting you answer and if no other reply, will accept it as answer just in case if anyone else has similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the database frist way. You have to create your models which will match with the database tables and create your DbContext.

The following page demonstrates an example of how to implement it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: hi pitaridis, thanks for the reply, but this doesn't solve my problem. In normal case it works but actually with Microsoft Identity, it creates its own tables like AspNetUsers etc to store user credentials. I have my own tables already with different names and different fields and I HAVE TO use it as the current live application heavily uses it. If I rename it, it'll break the application. That's why need to know how to use existing tables with Identity service. Thanks, Maulik

Comment: You do not have to use the identity tables. You can use your own users table.

Comment: hi Pitaridis, thanks for the reply. would you please explain how which is my original question? thanks Maulik

Comment: @user2325928 This answers only partially, but if you use the way I described above, the tables created will have the correct name.

Comment: BTW this article is nothing to do with identity. This is more about 'database first' with EFCore.